# How to open a txt file using the method getName()

Tags: java

```
 File file = new File("C:/mydirectory/");
    File[] files = file.listFiles();
    for(File f: files){
        System.out.println(f.getName());
```

`f.getName()` contains the name of the file but how can I open the file using `f.getName() ;`? Or please help me to open all the txt files using a loop.

Comment: by ''open" do you mean, read via program?

Comment: you already have them open in the variable `f`. Just print the contents of the file (if that's what you are intending to do).

Comment: By "open" I want to mean "How can I display all  the files "

Comment: what does "display" mean? printing the file content?

Comment: display means  I want to show the created file after clicking jbutton using f.getname().

Comment: display like a `JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, f.getName()+" created");`?

Answer (score 0):

```
if (f.getName().contains("name wanted")) {
FileInputStream fis = null;
   try (fis = new FileInputStream(f);
    // use the file input stream to read data
    }
```

or to read lines from the file

```
try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file))) {
    String line;
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
       // process the line.
    }
}
```

To display the name of all files you can use recursion, to get contents see above

```
public void display(File f) {
    File[] files = file.listFiles();
    for(File f: files){
        if (f.isDirectory()) {
           display(f);
         } else if (f.getName().contains("value")) {
           System.out.println(f.getName());
          }
}
```

and call this as `display(new File("C:/mydirectory/"))` from a main method.

Answer (score 0):

For read the whole file to `List<String>` use `Files.readAllLines(f.toPath())` or `Files.newInputStream(f.toPath())` for opening stream.

Comment: Please edit with more information. Code-only and "try this" answers are discouraged, because they contain no searchable content, and don't explain why someone should "try this". We make an effort here to be a resource for knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

you can 'display' your result using [JOptionPane](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html#showMessageDialog(java.awt.Component,%20java.lang.Object))

```
File file = new File("C:/mydirectory/");
String result = "";
for (String fileName: file.listFiles()){
    result = result+"\n";
}  
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, result);
```

`JOptionPane`grants static access, so you won't need any instances, the *first parameter* is the parent frame, null is allowed. The *second parameter* is the message (here: a list of all files within `C:/mydirectory/`) you want to 'display' ...